# ClearTimeout set in another tab

Tags: javascript, browser, timeout, settimeout, cleartimeout

How can I clear `timeout` that has been set in another `tab` in browser?

I tried by storing timeout reference in `localStorage`, but could not clear `timeout`

```
function setIdleTimeout() {
    var idleTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        //autologout
    }, 20000);
    localStorage.setItem('idleTimeout', idleTimeout);
}

function clearIdleTimeout() {
    var idleTimeout = localStorage.getItem('idleTimeout');
    clearTimeout(idleTimeout);
    localStorage.setItem('idleTimeout', idleTimeout);
}
```

If I call `clearIdleTimeout()` in second tab, it does not clear the `timeout` set in `previous tab`

Comment: You cannot do that unless both tabs are from the same domain, and you've got a link from one to the other (via `window.opener` or something like that). The timer identifiers are just numbers, and there's an implicit per-window namespace.

Comment: both tabs are on same domain, I'm implementing autologout feature if user is idle, but don't want first tab to logout user, since he is working on second tab

Comment: `idleTimeout` appears to be a string, not a variable

Comment: @guest271314 not following you :-/

Comment: @dzona Try `var timeout = null; timeout = setTimeout(function() {}, 20000); console.log(timeout)` . Try converting `localStorage.getItem('idleTimeout');` to a `Number()`; e.g., `clearTimeout(Number(localStorage.getItem("idleTimeout")))` , though `js` at Question does not appear to declare `idleTimeout = setTimeout()` ?

Comment: The two windows are in different context so no you will not able to clear the timeout. All that is in the localstorage is a string and it is meaningless to the other tab.

Comment: @epascarello It could be possible, though not trivial, using `SharedWorker` ,  `ServiceWorker` possibly `window.postMessage()` or `MessageChannel`

Comment: Or by using a listener in localStorage that bit gets flipped. There are ways to do it, but it will require code, but the way the OP wants to do it is not going to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tab` "a"

```
var timeout, interval;

timeout = setTimeout(function() {
  alert(123) // this should not be called
  clearTimeout(timeout)
  timeout = null;
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = null;
}, 20000);
localStorage.setItem("timeout", timeout);

interval = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("checking localStorage:", localStorage.getItem("timeout"));
  // if `!localStorage.getItem("timeout")` : `true` 
  // call `clearTimeout()` with `timeout` as paramter
  if (!localStorage.getItem("timeout")) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;
    alert("cleared");
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
  }
}, 100)
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/wttPFS5RLgCu5OnF05Z1?p=info

`tab` "b"

```
var t;
t = setTimeout(clearTabTimeout, 5000);

// clear `timeout` at `tab` "a"
function clearTabTimeout() {
  // remove `"timeout"` item from `localStorage`
  localStorage.removeItem("timeout");
  console.log(localStorage);
}
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/CgQqlVIUzUo7zeHCb2Ca?p=preview

Comment: I'll accept this as answer even though I don't like overhead by checking localStorage timeout flag, set by other tab. But +1 for the idea, which led me to solution for problem I was trying to solve in the first place. Thanks @guest271314

Comment: @dzona how did you end up solving this?