# How do I know a div is display: none in two or more tabs of a browser?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Consider I've this page: **sample.php**

```
<div id="id1" style="display: none">
Hello
</div>
```

Initially when the page loads, this div is **not** displayed, but I've a **button1**. When I click on this button, it changes the display value to **block**.

There's another **button2** that I use to change the display value back to **none**.

So, this div is visible only when the **button1** is clicked. In other cases (when the page is reloaded or when **button2** is clicked), it would be invisible.

Now, suppose that I've opened this same page in 4 more tabs (it can be even more, I'm giving just example) of a browser. And I've pressed **button1** in **any 2** of them. That means this div is visible in those **2** tabs.

Now, what I want is that when the div is visible, the text inside it should store in a **SESSION** variable. And I can do it using JavaScript, jQuery, Ajax and PHP. When the **two tabs** have **2 visible** divs, their text "**Hello**" is stored in a same **SESSION** variable (it will store only "Hello" only, **not "HelloHello"** since SESSION will get replaced by new request as my Ajax and PHP code will run on all tabs at the same time).

Now what I finally need is that when those **2 visible** divs in **2** differents tabs are set to **display: none**, it should unset the SESSION variable that has "Hello" in it.

Because my condition for unsetting it is that none of the **4** tabs should have that div visible. If any of the tab has div visible, the SESSION would have "Hello" in it.

PS: I've tried to explain a lot my problem, but still if you don't understand, please mention it in comment, before answering:

Thank you.

Comment: In short you are using the session variable to check if the div is displayed right?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload/30144363#30144363 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36146595/can-we-refer-to-javascript-variables-across-webpages-in-a-browser-session/36146764#36146764 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190731/cleartimeout-set-in-another-tab/36191942#36191942

Comment: @Anoopsaju, no, I'm using JavaScript to check the visibility, and if it is visible, I'm storing the text inside into the SESSION variable.

Comment: Instead of checking the visibility,you can store the text into the session variable when the button1 is clicked

Comment: I want to store it only when it is visible, and delete it when it's not visible in all tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code ,when button1 or **show button** is clicked,it will send the data to **new.php.**

The **new.php** will **set** the session variable.I have use another session variable **count** for taking the count of the number of tabs in which it is visible.

When the **hide button** is clicked,  a post request is sent and the session variable count is reduced.When the count variable is reduced to 0 ,  there are no more tabs in which it is visible.So the session is destroyed

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="jquery/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $("#show").click(function(){
   $("#id1").css("display","block");
   var x=$("#id1").text();
   $.post("new.php",{val: x});
 });

 $("#hide").click(function(){
   $("#id1").css("display","none");
   $.post("new.php");

});
 });
 </script>
 </head>
<body>
  <div id="id1" style="display: none">
  Hello
  </div>
 <button type="button" id="show">show</button>
 <button type="button" id="hide">Hide</button>

 </body>
  </html>
```

**new.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!empty($_POST["val"]))
{
  if(!isset($_SESSION["val"]))
  {
    $_SESSION["val"]=$_POST["val"];
    $_SESSION["count"]=1;
   }
  else {
    $_SESSION["count"]+=1;
  }
}
else
{
  if(isset($_SESSION["val"]))
  {
    if($_SESSION["count"]==1)
    {
      session_destroy();
    }
   else {
     $_SESSION["count"]-=1;

    }
 }
 }


 ?>
```