# window.opener is returing null

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have a link in `www.abc.com` , clicking on which it opens up a popup from `www.def.com` .
There is a form in that popup from `www.def.com`. After clicking upon the "Save" button on the form I want the current window to be closed
and the parent will should redirect to a location.

Before this change when I was showing the form from www.abc.com, the below code was working fine .

```
<script language="JavaScript">        
  parent.window.close();
  parent.opener.parent.window[1].location.replace('/abc.jsp?custid=12345');
</script>
```

But now `"parent.opener" is returning null`. So I am able to close the popup but not able to redirect the parent window to
disired location.

I know what I am asking is bit wired, But this the requirement.

Comment: `def.com` is a different domain. May require using `postMessage()` or other cross domain messaging method. You should be able to use `document.referrer` at new `window` to reference the url which opened new `window`

Comment: @guest271314 Yes 'dcoument.referrer' giving me the url that opened this new window. But how should I redirect in that window?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: @guest271314: `window.opener` itself returning null in my case because of cross domain, then how `window.open.postMessage` will work on the popup?

Comment: If you can add `<script>` at "def" URL, you should be able to call `.postMessage()`. If this does not return expected result,  you could try using `localStorage` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190731/cleartimeout-set-in-another-tab/ ; host URL's in `iframe` and use `MessageChannel` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645685/how-to-clear-the-contents-of-an-iframe-from-another-iframe/; or use `SharedWorker` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36146595/can-we-refer-to-javascript-variables-across-webpages-in-a-browser-session/

Comment: @guest271314 : `If you can add <script> at "def" URL, you should be able to call .postMessage()`, Strange but in the `def` url , `console.log(window.opener)` is returning me `null`.

Comment: Does "abc" open "def"? If `.postMessage()` does not return expected results, you can try using `localStorage`

Comment: @guest271314 Yes it does open the popup. In the plunker demo are you using two different domains as i explained?

Comment: Try `window.postMessage("redirect.html",    
      document.referrer);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At "abc.moc"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    // open `popup`
    var popup = window.open("popup.html", "popup", "width=200,height=200");
    // handler `message` event from `popup.html`
    function receiveMessage(event) {
      console.log(event, event.data);
      this.location.href = event.data;
    }
    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

at "def.moc"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Save">
  </form>
    <script>
    console.log(window.opener);
    var button = document.querySelector("form input[type=button]");
    button.onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      // do stuff with `form`
      // call `.postMessage()` on `window.opener` with 
      // first parameter URL to redirect `abc.moc`,
      // second parameter `location.href` of `abc.moc`
      window.opener.postMessage("redirect.html",    
      window.opener.location.href);
      // close `popup`
      window.close();
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/pK4XBJDrqFrE7awvMlZj?p=preview