# Select Parent Window Option From Child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typeahead.js

I am trying to auto select an option in the parent window based on the text search in the pop-up window. Using typeahead I am only able to search on the text value, not its ID so I need to compare that way.

```
 //Parent Window
<form>
<select name="recipient_id" id="recipient_id">
    <option value="">----</option>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</select> <a href="javascript://" onClick="window.open(url,'_pop','width=500,height=400,status=0,directory=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1'); return false;">Search By Name/Company</a>
</form>

//Search Window
<form id="form-attendee" name="form-attendee">
<input class="js-typeahead-attendee" id="js-typeahead-attendee" name="attendee" type="search" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">

 <button type="submit">
    <i class="typeahead__search-icon"></i>
 </button>
</form>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
               $("#form-attendee").submit(function() {
                    var recipientID = window.opener.$("#recipient_id");
                    $(recipientID).find("option[text='" + $("#js-typeahead-attendee").val() + "']").attr("selected", true);
                    self.close();
               });
           });

//Typeahead code here
    </script>
```

[Used this as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644449/jquery-setting-select-list-selected-based-on-text-failing-strangely) and while I'm not getting an error the parent window is not updating.

You can test this out on http://chemoutsourcing.com/test.php. Click the link on this page will bring a pop up that allows you to search for the names in the parent window drop down list.

Comment: Can you create a plunker http://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: I added a link above that you can test my work on.

Comment: `<option>` elements at parent `window` do not have `text` attribute; try substituting `$(recipientID).find("option[value='" + $("#js-typeahead-attendee").val() + "']").attr("selected", true);` for `$(recipientID).find("option[text='" + $("#js-typeahead-attendee").val() + "']").attr("selected", true);`

Comment: Nice idea but it didn't take.

Comment: You can try using `MessageChannel`, `SharedWorker`, or `localStorage`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645685/how-to-clear-the-contents-of-an-iframe-from-another-iframe/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36146595/can-we-refer-to-javascript-variables-across-webpages-in-a-browser-session , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190731/cleartimeout-set-in-another-tab/